# Deluge bit torrent. No incoming connections?

Tags: 12.04, deluge

Hi I keep getting a no incoming connections on my Deluge. I know this is a pretty common problem from Google, but I have posted here to see if any one knows why this happens.

I have port forwarded my router and set Deluge to the correct port range.

Is this just a bug ? It does not seem to affect the speed so I obviously do have incoming connections and Transmission says the ports are open.

So I guess my question is why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Deluge is a torrent client. While nobody is connecting to you, you are connecting to others through their forwarded ports. You can:

- Disable your firewall and allow it to pass the pots you have forwarded.
- Use a different torrent with more seeders and peers(Sometimes called seeds, sources, and leechers). Please note that I, personally, do not condone the use of illegal peer-to-peer sources, and by seeding/using a torrent, you may be illegally sharing data depending on the content of the torrent.
- Add a tracker that you think has more peers(I cannot recommend a tracker, sorry).
- Add peers manually if you know their IP addresses and post numbers(They must be on the same torrent).
- Try to bootstrap with DHT:

  1. Run a popular torrent with many peers
  2. Keep that torrent paused while you run your slow torrent
- Wait.

> Note that using BitTorrent(r) or using peer-to-peer services may be illegal in your area. Myself and any editor(s) of this answer are not responsible for any damages, incidental, or consequential, that may arise from use of these instructions. The use of torrents implies your sharing data with other peers(users) and is punishable by action from the US Federal Bureau of Investigation or your local authorities if the data being transferred is copyrighted, illegal, or protected by the Digital Millennium Copyright Act.

Comment: That is good info but this is a Deluge specific issue other clients don't have this problem

Comment: @markkirby Have you set Deluge to the correct ports? Try a few different(legal) torrents. Also, if you are getting good bandwidth, you should be good, and these is no need to worry.

Comment: P2P can be illegal?!? What about perfectly legit torrents? (ie Linux distros)

Comment: @Vreality Pardon that little mistake. Anyway, even if you *are* using P2P for downloading a Linux distro, certain ISPs seem to ignore that fact, and still mail you an irate letter.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Wow. Well that would be rather annoying. My ISP has not complained as of yet.

Comment: @Vreality It's a new law in the USA.